# gcc - how to find path of header include file

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, gcc-warning

Do we have any option in gcc to find from where a particular file header is included.
I have the following scenario :

file_1.h :
declare type of type_1

file_2.h :

type_1 var;

I want to check where was file_1.h included in the library that i am creating.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

gcc has an option -M:

> -M  Instead of outputting the result of preprocessing, output a
>   rule suitable for make describing the dependencies of the main source
>   file.  The preprocessor outputs one
>          make rule containing the object file name for that source file, a colon, and the names of all the included files, including those
>   coming from -include or -imacros
>          command line options.

If you do, `gcc -M filename.c`, it'll list out all headers. Same with g++.

Comment: <del>Is there a similar flag for clang++?</del> -M also works for clang. My mistake was trying to use -M and -c at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the preprocessed output it will show the headers that were included, in the order they were included, so you can see where file_1.h appears and work backwards to see which file included it, and which file included that etc.

The `-E` option tells GCC to only perform the preprocessing step and to stop before compilation.